# How to properly turn this string into a correct structure?

Tags: vb.net

```
Structure WeightElement 'The Weights are stored in an array of Weight Elemenets, which are used as a tree
    Dim LowPointer As Integer
    Dim HighPointer As Integer
    Dim TraitPointer As Integer 'This pointer allows another tree to be appended to certain elements, for the sake of dependent traits
    Dim Values As WeightedTrait()
    Dim Num As Integer 'The Weight Elements are named by numbers for ease of comparison
End Structure
Structure WeightedTrait
    Dim TraitName As String 'This is the value that is displayed to the user when a character is made
    Dim TraitNum As Integer 'The trait number is used to find the correct element in trait sub-trees
    Dim WeightValue As Decimal
End Structure
Function ChewQuery(QueryList As String)
    'This function takes in a string and partitions it into a weight tree
    Dim ElementList() As String
    ElementList = QueryList.Split(";")
    Dim LoadedWeight(ElementList.Length) As WeightElement
    For x = 0 To ElementList.Length - 1
        'Using this method, in which the front portion of the query is repeatedly removed, allows for a simpler query structure, so that we don't need to partition between the pointers and values
        LoadedWeight(x).LowPointer = CInt(BiteQuery(ElementList(x)))
        LoadedWeight(x).HighPointer = CInt(BiteQuery(ElementList(x)))
        LoadedWeight(x).TraitPointer = CInt(BiteQuery(ElementList(x)))
        LoadedWeight(x).Num = CInt(BiteQuery(ElementList(x)))
        ChewQueryValues(ElementList(x), LoadedWeight(x))
    Next
    Return LoadedWeight
End Function
Function BiteQuery(ByRef QueryList As String)
    Dim Marker As Integer
    Dim Bite As String
    'This function partitions the input string around the first comma
    'It returns the section before the comma, and stores the section behind the comma as the new value for the string
    Try
        Marker = InStr(QueryList, ",")
        Bite = Left(QueryList, Marker - 1)
        Marker = Len(QueryList) - Marker
        QueryList = Right(QueryList, Marker)
    Catch
        'This is used in the case that a list without a comma is input
        Bite = QueryList
        QueryList = ""
    End Try
    Return Bite
End Function
Sub ChewQueryValues(ByRef QueryList As String, ByRef LoadedWeight As WeightElement)
    LoadedWeight.Values = {}
    While Len(QueryList) > 0
        'This While loop is so that an arbitrary number of values can be inserted
        'Because BiteQuery takes in functions by reference, each loop reduces the length of the string until it is empty
        ReDim Preserve LoadedWeight.Values(LoadedWeight.Values.Length + 1)
        LoadedWeight.Values(LoadedWeight.Values.Length - 1).TraitName = BiteQuery(QueryList)
        LoadedWeight.Values(LoadedWeight.Values.Length - 1).TraitNum = CInt(BiteQuery(QueryList))
        LoadedWeight.Values(LoadedWeight.Values.Length - 1).WeightValue = CDec(BiteQuery(QueryList))
    End While
End Sub
```

These subroutines should transform a properly formatted string into a WeightElement array. The string I am using is:

```
1,2,0,5,Black,26,1,White,30,1,EastAsian,27,1,SouthAsian,28,1,MiddleEastern,29,1;3,4,25,3,N/A,0,1;28,5,6,13,N/A,0,1;-1,7,0,1,Male,16,1,Female,17,1,Non-Binary,18,1;-1,-1,8,4,N/A,0,1;-1,34,9,15,N/A,0,1;10,11,0,28,Light,-1,1,Medium,-1,1;-1,-1,12,2,N/A,0,1;13,14,0,21,Andro,19,1,Gyno,20,1,A,21,1,Bi,22,1,Pan,23,1;15,16,0,28,Straight,-1,1,Wavy,-1,1,Curly,-1,1;-1,17,0,26,Light,-1,1,Medium,-1,1,Dark,-1,1;18,-1,0,30,Pale,-1,1,Light,-1,1;19,20,0,17,Male,31,1,Female,32,1,Intersex,33,1;-1,21,0,19,Andro,19,1,Gyno,20,1,A,21,1,Bi,22,1,Pan,23,1;22,-1,0,23,Andro,19,1,Gyno,20,1,A,21,1,Bi,22,1,Pan,23,1;-1,23,0,26,Curly,-1,1,Coily,-1,1;24,-1,0,30,Straight,-1,1,Wavy,-1,1,Curly,-1,1;-1,-1,0,27,Pale,-1,1,Light,-1,1,Medium,-1,1;-1,-1,0,29,Pale,-1,1,Light,-1,1,Medium,-1,1;-1,-1,0,16,Male,31,1,Female,32,1,Intersex,33,1;-1,-1,0,18,Male,31,1,Female,32,1,Intersex,33,1;-1,-1,0,20,Andro,19,1,Gyno,20,1,A,21,1,Bi,22,1,Pan,23,1;-1,-1,0,22,Andro,19,1,Gyno,20,1,A,21,1,Bi,22,1,Pan,23,1;-1,-1,0,27,Straight,-1,1,Wavy,-1,1;-1,-1,0,29,Straight,-1,1,Wavy,-1,1,Curly,-1,1;26,27,0,17,Andro,19,1,Gyno,20,1,A,21,1,Bi,22,1,Pan,23,1;-1,-1,0,16,Andro,19,1,Gyno,20,1,A,21,1,Bi,22,1,Pan,23,1;-1,-1,0,18,Andro,19,1,Gyno,20,1,A,21,1,Bi,22,1,Pan,23,1;29,30,0,8,Albinism,-1,1,ChronicFatigue,-1,1,Dwarfism,-1,1;-1,31,0,6,Autistic,-1,1,ADHD,-1,1,OCD,-1,1,Tourrette,-1,1,Epilepsy,-1,1;32,33,35,10,N/A,0,1;-1,-1,0,7,OneArmAbsent,-1,1,BothArmsAbsent,-1,1,OneHandwithAnomalies,-1,1,BothHandswithAnomalies,-1,1,OneLegAbsent,26,1,BothLegsAbsent,26,1;-1,-1,36,9,N/A,0,1;-1,-1,0,11,GoodHearing,-1,1,HardofHearing,-1,1,Deaf,-1,1,NoHearing,-1,1;-1,-1,0,34,Scars,-1,1,NaturalAnomalies,-1,1,OneEyeAbsent,-1,1,BothEyesAbsent,-1,1;-1,37,0,0,GoodVision,-1,1,Blind,-1,1,NoVision,-1,1;-1,38,0,0,Unaided,-1,1,Cane,-1,1,Wheelchair,-1,1,Full-TimeWheelchair,-1,1;-1,-1,0,25,N/A,0,1;-1,-1,0,26,Unaided,-1,1,Cane,-1,1,Wheelchair,-1,1,Full-TimeWheelchair,-1,1
```

The format is that the first four values between each semicolon are the low pointer, high pointer, trait pointer, and Number, in that order. After this point are the values, with the trait name, trait number, and weight value, repeating in that order

When I use this string, the program decides to return a WeightElement array of the correct length, but where all the values are 0 or empty strings. How do I make it produce a proper WeightElement, as by the format above?

Comment: @pm100 There are semicolons in there.

Comment: I'd recommend running in the debugger and seeing where the behavior diverges from your expectations.